# Horizontal truncation property of Lebesgue integral

Tags: calculus, lebesgue-integral

From [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/09/19/245a-notes-2-the-lebesgue-integral/):

> Corollary 11 (Finite additivity of the Lebesgue integral) Let $f, g:
>  {\bf R}^d \rightarrow [0,+\infty]$ be measurable. Then $\int_{{\bf
>  R}^d} f(x)+g(x)\ dx = \int_{{\bf R}^d} f(x)\ dx + \int_{{\bf R}^d}
>  g(x)\ dx$.
>
> Proof: From the horizontal truncation property and a limiting
>   argument, we may assume that $f, g$ are bounded[...]

Could anyone tell me why do we assume that $f,g$ are bounded functions? We don't know if they are bounded or not - it's not stated in the assumptions. I just don't see where this conclusion comes from. Doesn't it contradict our assumptions?

Actually what I'm looking for is an informal explanation of what horizontal truncation property is all about, and also why we can assume $f,g$ are bounded, even if they may be unbounded.

Comment: Almost surely, the author wants you to consider $f_N = f \cdot 1_{|f| \leq N}$ and the analogous $g_N$. These are bounded. Then take $\lim_{N\to\infty}$ to obtain the result for the originally given $f,g$. Of course, there has to be some argument to justify the limit.

Comment: Then it should read 'Let's consider bounded $f_N$ and $g_N$' instead? We're not _literally_ assuming that $f,g$ are bounded, but only considering their bounded 'versions', right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full version of my comment:

The author wants you to consider $f_N = f \cdot 1_{|f| \leq N}$ and the analogous $g_N$. These are bounded, so that (if we have the result for bounded functions) the result holds for these. Then, we pass to the limit $N \to \infty$ and somehow have to verify that $\int f_N + g_N$ converges to $\int f+g$ and that $\int f_N \to \int f$ and likewise for $g$. One possibility here is to use monotone convergence (if that is already known).

Such an argumentation appears frequently in mathematical proofs. If the author just writes "we may assume [without loss of generality] that", it is meant that one can modify the original problem in a (more or less) obvious way so that the additional assumption is satisfied.

Afterwards, one can then derive the result for the original objects (functions, ...) by that for the modified ones, e.g. by taking some sort of limit, using linearity, ...

If the author thinks that these steps are obvious, they are (sadly) often omitted.

Otherwise, frequently at some point in the proof the modification and justification (e.g. for taking the limit) are spelled out explicitly.

It often happens to me that I get frustrated by not seeing the "obvious" modifications; then I stop reading to figure it out. Only after a lot of thinking, I then sometimes realize that the author tells me how to do it later in the proof :)

Comment: That's a weird way of reasoning. You prove a statement by changing the assumptions, proving the statement and then use limits to obtain initial assumptions without breaking the proof... right?

Comment: @user4205580: Yes, exactly. This is indeed quite common. Another example is to show a claim which you want to hold e.g. for all integrable functions (or $L^p$ functions) only for continuous/differentiable ("nice") ones and then use some kind of approximation argument to get the claim for arbitrary integrable functions.

Comment: Came back to ask one more thing - how do you define $1_{|f|\le N}$? It's equal to $1$ when $|f|\le N$ - otherwise $0$?

Comment: @user4205580: Yes, exactly. More precisely, $1_{|f|\leq N}(x) =1$ if $|f(x)| \leq N$ and $1_{|f|\leq N} (x) = 0$ otherwise.